# How to run several test cases for one fixture in Google Test?

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing, testing, googletest

Suppose that I have a Google Test fixture named `ProfileTest` inherited from `::testing::TestWithParams<T>` that creates a parser:

```
class ProfileTest:

public ::testing::TestWithParam<std::tuple<std::string,std::string>>{

public:
    QString getName(){
        return QFileInfo(*m_file).fileName();
    }

protected:
    void SetUp(){

        m_profile = new Profile();

        m_file = new QFile(std::get<0>(GetParam()).c_str());
        m_file->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);
        m_file->write(std::get<1>(GetParam()).c_str());
        m_file->close();

    }
    void TearDown(){

        delete m_file;

        delete m_profile;
    }

    Profile* m_profile;
    QFile *m_file;
};
```

Parametrized test case:

```
TEST_P(ProfileTest, TestProfileGoodFormedContent){
    ASSERT_NO_THROW(m_profile->readProfile(QFileInfo(*m_file)));
    ASSERT_STREQ(m_profile->name(), getName());
    ASSERT_GE(m_profile->getProfileConfigurations().size(),1);
}
```

I have added `TEST_CASE` with well-formed content, and anything works great.

Now I want to add `TEST_CASE` with bad-formed content, but `TestProfileGoodFormedContent` `TEST_P` is unsuitable for testing bad content.

I suppose I should add a new `TEST_P`, but it will have same `fixture(ProfileTest)` that brings me an error that all test cases will be provided to any `TEST_P` that have `ProfileTest` as fixture.

What should I do to test well-formed content and bad-formed content simultaneously?

Comment: Couldn't you add a boolean to your parameter set, and that boolean indicates whether the content is well formed or not? Then when you write your `TEST_P` you can have different asserts based on whether or not it is well formed.

Comment: @NirFriedman That is bad practice. If the test fails, it is unclear from the output what was the value of the boolean flag when the test failed. And yes, you can add additional printing but there are better ways to tackle this.

Comment: Do you really need `TestWithParam`? By that, I mean do you really need several well-formed and several ill-formed values, or are you planning just two versions (one for well-formed and one for ill-formed)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, you need as many Google Test fixtures as you have different scenarios.

Of course, you can have base fixture class - that will sets up for you common things:

```
class ProfileTestBase :

public ::testing::TestWithParam<std::tuple<std::string,std::string>>{

public:
    QString getName(){
        return QFileInfo(*m_file).fileName();
    }

protected:
    void SetUp(){

        m_profile = new Profile();

        m_file = new QFile(std::get<0>(GetParam()).c_str());
        m_file->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);
        m_file->write(std::get<1>(GetParam()).c_str());
        m_file->close();

    }
    void TearDown(){

        delete m_file;

        delete m_profile;
    }

    Profile* m_profile;
    QFile *m_file;
};
```

So - basically your current class will become base class.

For Good/Bad/Whatever-else - create specific fixture classes:

```
class GoodProfileTest : public ProfileTestBase {};
class BadProfileTest : public ProfileTestBase {};
```

You current "good" profile test would belongs to GoodProfileTest:

```
TEST_P(GoodProfileTest, TestProfileGoodFormedContent){
    ASSERT_NO_THROW(m_profile->readProfile(QFileInfo(*m_file)));
    ASSERT_STREQ(m_profile->name(), getName());
    ASSERT_GE(m_profile->getProfileConfigurations().size(),1);
}
```

Whatever you need to be tested as bad profile - use BadProfileTest class. And so on... Of course - you need to use INSTANTIATE_*** macros for every fixtures.